# How would you best translate "to make one + verb"

Tags: grammaire

I would like to know the correct way to translate "to make one + verb". In this case, "make" is to compel or make someone feel compelled to do something.

Like the case: 

*What made you want/feel like learning other languages?*

Would it be:

Qu'est-ce qui t'a rendu envie d'apprendre d'autres langues?

According to [this](http://french.about.com), make followed by verb is 'faire'; however, I am not sure.

Although the person I was speaking to seemed to understand me, and answered with the correct answer, yet he never corrected me.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: I will try to fix it, my apologies!

Comment: @jlliagre I have fixed the link for future reference, for you've answered my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are possible ways to say it:

> Qu'est-ce qui t'a incité à apprendre d'autres langues ?
>
> Qu'est-ce qui t'a donné envie d'apprendre d'autres langues ?

Comment: Also: "Qu'est-ce qui t'a donné le goût d'apprendre d'autres langues?", "D'où te vient l'envie (le goût) d'apprendre d'autres langues?"

Comment: I like the 2nd option! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: I didn't even think of that option thanks so much!

Comment: To be more litteral, you could use "Qu'est-ce qui t'a **fait** avoir envie d'apprendre d'autres langues". The only problem is that "fait avoir envie d'apprendre" makes 3 verbs (4 with auxiliary) very close, so a bit heavy... In an other context, you would use "faire" this way